# Change of basis in a rotation

Tags: rotations, change-of-basis

This must be very elementary, but I am really stuck after much reading.

Given a vector **v** and a basis A, to find **v**'s coordinates in a new basis A' which is a rotation of A by angle θ, I understand that you must proceed as follows:

a) Find the coordinates in the original basis A of the unit vectors of the new basis (say **e<sub>1</sub>'** and **e<sub>2</sub>'**), which happen to be as shown in this picture:

[image: change of basis]

b) To get coordinate v<sub>1</sub>' in the new basis A', make the dot product between **v** (coordinates in A) and **e<sub>1</sub>'** (also as per coordinates in A); whereas for v<sub>2</sub>', you would need dot product with again **v** but **e<sub>2</sub>'** in this case.

My problem is with a), second part. I see that a projection of **e<sub>1</sub>'** over X axis gives out cosθ as x coordinate and sinθ as y coordinate. But if we repeated the same projection with **e<sub>2</sub>** over X axis, we would get -cosθ and sinθ, which is not the right answer.

I tend to think that my initial mistake, in the second problematic case, was projecting over X. After all, here the rotation starts from **e<sub>2</sub>**, not from **e<sub>1</sub>**, even if it is the same number of degrees... So I hypothesized that I should project **e<sub>2</sub>'** **over e<sub>2</sub>** and then somehow convert the result into the language of the initial angle for the sake of homogeneity. Thus for the first coordinate I got a cos, which would be equivalent of a sine in terms of the first angle, but why then the negative sign, so I am lost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exercise involves the two complementary ideas of [active and passive transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation): (a) rotating a vector, and obtaining its new coordinates in a fixed coordinate system, and (b) rotating the coordinate system, and obtaining the new coordinates of a fixed vector.

For part (a) the coordinates of the rotated basis vectors $\mathbf{e}_1'$ and $\mathbf{e}_2'$ are already correctly marked on the diagram: 
they are respectively $(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$ 
and $(-\sin\alpha,\cos\alpha)$.
(In your description, $\theta$ is the same as $\alpha$).
I can't quite follow why you are having difficulty with the second of these:
if you take the point at the end of the rotated vector $\mathbf{e}_2'$
and project (vertically) onto the original $x$ axis, the intercept is $-\sin\alpha$, while if you project (horizontally) onto the original $y$ axis, the intercept is $\cos\alpha$.

For part (b), the procedure is exactly as you describe: for some arbitrary fixed vector $\mathbf{v}$ you need to work out the projections onto the new axis system. One way to do this is to compute the scalar products with the new basis vectors, and you can do this if you express $\mathbf{v}$, $\mathbf{e}_1'$ and $\mathbf{e}_2'$ in the original coordinate system. But, if I understand you correctly, you don't have a problem with that.

Both active and passive rotations can be expressed as the 
product of a vector with a rotation matrix of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad \text{or} \qquad
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Knowing which one to use, and the sign convention to adopt for clockwise and anticlockwise rotation angles,
are always sources of confusion.
The best way to avoid this is to work through examples
of exactly the kind that you are doing.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I was obfuscated because I was thinking of the typical unit circle with a single rotating vector. But here we have two basis vectors that have been rotated and in each case "cosine" is the side from which you rotate, since the triangle is between the original axis and its rotated version... The other side is the opposite one hence "sine" and I gather that it is negative... just because the rotation of e2 is pointing down, whereas that of e1 was pointing up?

Comment: It is sometimes helpful to think about the limiting case when the angle is very small, so in both cases the new basis vector is only slightly different from the original basis vector with the same index (1 or 2). For e2, the sine term comes with a negative sign because (on your diagram, where the angle is positive and not very large) the e2 vector has been rotated anti-clockwise so it ends up to the left of the original e2 (y axis). In other words, when you project it vertically downwards onto the x axis, the intercept lies at a negative value of x.

Comment: You perfectly clarified it, last sentence is very clear. So you paved the way for another question in continuation, here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2920869/how-to-interpret-the-change-of-basis-matrix